# Colect data for multiples websites at once

Tags: php, html, database

There is a way I can collect the info of 15000 different url at once ?

**For example:**

I have the website https://example.com/50 and I want to collect the info 3 specific span id (igual in every website )
The value I want is the value of the *data-price*

```
<span id="lowest-1" data-price="800">800</span>
<span id="lowest-2" data-price="900">900</span>
<span id="lowest-3" data-price="700">700</span>
```

I want to collect the data from https://example.com/1 to https://example.com/15000

Note:
I do not have access to the database, only the webpages

Comment: What do you mean by "At once" (standard) PHP doesn't have any sense of multithreading so you would have to make one request after another. But im sure you could use a language that does allow for async calls

Comment: do not need to be at once but like in a space of 5 to 15 minutes collect 15000 values of 15000 different url and repeat again 3 hours later

Comment: The thing is that load all the webpages with images and everything will use a lot of resources. I want to load only the info needed

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are two problems:

- first: PHP cannot establih 15000 connections at once, you must do that one by one
- second: it take same time to fetch content from remote website, typically half of second

Rough calculation: you need 7500 seconds for that (2 hours).

It is bad idea to forcing PHP to execute so long.

Split that array of links in chunks, for example 30 links in chunk,
and use CRON system to periodically execute your worker script to fetching data.
Alternative approach can be to make AJAX call to your worker and when it receive response javascript automatically trigger next AJAX call, but you need to keep your browser open.

Worker will store collected data into database and your frontend reading data from that table. Worker works independently of frontend so frontend is unaware where is worker in execution loop, it just shows last known data.

This is a way how web crawlers (spiders) works.

Are you owner of these 1500 websites? If you are than you can make some fast-accessible endpoint there to collect data (RSS, REST,..). That can significally reduce crawling time.

Comment: I´m not the owner of the website. This does not sound the easiest way, i can not load the full page to collect only a bit of information.
is there another way other than PHP ?

Comment: With PHP you can easily retrieve HTML of page, without images and scripts. But yes, whole page. There is no way to get only part of page.

Comment: is it a good use python with BeautifulSoup library ?